# Как вычленить из строки все числа типа `int` в массив за О(n)?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки

Дана строка, заполненная случайным образом. Например, 4jkk8653kl87-43@Wf23457754345. Можно ли за О(n) вычленить из неё **в порядке слева направо** все числа типа `int` в массив? Для нашего примера: 4,8653,87,-43.

Comment: Что понимать под термином "без вложенных циклов"? Если имеется в виду "за один проход по строке" - то можно. Как это реализовать совсем без вложенных циклов - не знаю.

Comment: @andy.37 Квадратичная сложность и линейная - есть разница?

Comment: @georgiy-barsukov. Есть. Поэтому и уточняю. Вложенные циклы в алгоритме будут, но сложность будет линейная

Comment: @andy.37 понял, изменил вопрос

Comment: С помощью регулярного выражения можно

Comment: @Umed, с каких пор у регулярок линейная ассимптотика? К тому же, они достанут результат в виде строк.

Comment: @andy.37, а я и без вложенных циклов могу, хотя с ними проще и действий меньше.

Comment: @Qwertiy как???

Comment: @Qwertiy, хммм...? ИМХО, нужен же цикл типа `while(digit)` внутри цикла `while(мы еще в строке)`

Comment: @Qwertiy я думал пройти одним циклом от конца к началу с помощью pow(10,i). А потом перевернуть полученный массив. Не будет ли это слишком затратно?

Comment: @Georgiy_Barsukov, никаких `pow` не нужно, это будет велосипед, вполне вероятно, что с квадратными колесами. Есть же ф-ии стандартных библиотек типа `atoi`, `atol`.

Comment: @andy.37 я имел в виду получение разрядов. Так будет быстрее, нежели циклы в циклах. Но если массив слишком большой, то переворачивать противно

Comment: @Georgiy_Barsukov, сомневаюсь, что мы с Вами реализуем `atoi` быстрее, чем это сделано в `cstdlib`.

Comment: @andy.37 для atoi параметром является строка, поэтому **нужно выделять подстроки** из начальной строки. А для составления чисел по разрядам с конца нужен один цикл на всю строку.  Я не говорил, что переведу строку в число быстрее, чем atoi

Comment: @Georgiy_Barsukov, подстроку можно формировать по ходу движения по строке. Сложность не увеличится.

Comment: @andy.37 ладно, воспользуюсь stdlib, спасибо

Comment: Можно же проходя по массиву заменять все "не цифры" на '\0' и сохранять указатель (индекс) на начало каждой подстроки, которая является числом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char c[] = "sadfaghf123454hfdgsh4352hdgf43256";
while (c[i] != '\0') {
    if (c[i] >= '0' && c[i] <= '9')
        i = get_number(c+i, next_number); // i - след. индекс не цифры, в нумбер пишем число.
    else
        i = skip_non_digit_chars(c+i); // i - след. индекс цифры bkb '\0'
}
```

В функциях `get_number` и `skip_non_digit_chars` будут циклы типа `while (is_digit(c[i])) { ...}`

Это, естественно, не решение, так, набросок алгоритма, но здесь не любят делать задачи за Вас целиком)

Comment: `while (c[i] != '\0')`

Comment: @Georgiy_Barsukov, спс, очепятка ессно.

Answer (score 4):

http://ideone.com/fGuRWG

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
const char *s="4jkk8653kl87-43@Wf23457754345", *p;
vector <long long> res;
long long cur;
bool neg;

for(p=s; *p; ++p)
  if(*p=='-' || *p>='0' && *p<='9')
    {
    cur = (neg = *p=='-') ? 0 : *p-'0';
    while(*++p>='0' && *p<='9') cur = cur*10 + *p - '0';
    --p;
    res.push_back(neg ? -cur : cur);
    }

for(unsigned q=0; q<res.size(); ++q)
  cout << res[q] << ' ';

return 0;
}
```

Comment: читабельненько)

Comment: Ха!... `for(...) if(...) while(...) { ... }`. Это не вложенный цикл?! ))) Но красиво.

Comment: `vector` можно убрать и выводить значения сразу.

Comment: Кстати, у вас на выходе: 4 8653 87 -43 23457754345

Comment: @andy.37 а как Вы хотели проверить символ на цифру без цикла? Развернуть его в цепочку if'ов? Это будет действительно смешно. Я бы предложил использовать `isdigit`, там может быть вообще табличная функция (т.е. без циклов).

Comment: @Georgiy_Barsukov, кстати, хотел поинтересоваться, а почему у Вас 23457754345 не должно попасть в результат? Типа, в int не влезет?

Comment: @alexolut, дак и я о том, что вложенные циклы таки будут в алгоритме.

Comment: @andy.37 если проверку делать по таблице, то не будет.

Comment: @andy.37 да, и вот по этому поводу:
"Существует не стандартная ситуация, когда преобразованное значение выйдет из диапазона принимаемых значений типа данных int. Поэтому, предусмотрена более надежная кросс-платформенная альтернатива — функция strtol." Пожалуй, ей и воспользуюсь

Comment: @andy.37, это с циклами. Без циклов см. рядом и соответствующий вопрос - не могу понять, в чём там косяк.

Comment: @Georgiy_Barsukov, а что не так с выводом? У тебя в вопросе про -43 написан же.

Comment: @Qwertiy? у меня все выполнилось на ideone.

Comment: @andy.37 http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/473901/178988 - там две ссылки на ideone - в первой превышение времени работы (вероятно, вечный цикл?), во второй добавлен cout и всё хорошо. ЧЯДНТ?

Comment: @Qwertiy, в том то и дело, что у меня без cout работает.

Comment: @andy.37, нажал fork - действительно работает... Магия. Но у меня есть охапка изменений и без него стабильно не работало.

Comment: @andy.37, ideone глючит - приходится пересоздавать вмесито редактирования. На что бы заменить?

Answer (score 1):

Вот демонстрационная программа, которая показывает, как это можно сделать.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::string s( "4jkk8653kl87-43@Wf23457754345" );
    std::vector<int> v;

    for ( std::string::size_type pos = 0; 
          ( pos = s.find_first_of( "0123456789", pos ) ) != std::string::npos; )
    {
        char *p;
        int value = ( int )std::strtol( s.c_str() + pos, &p, 10 );
        v.push_back( value );
        pos = p - s.c_str();
    }          

    for ( int value : v ) std::cout << value << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
4 8653 87 43 2147483647
```

Так как у вас могут быть очень длинные значения, то вместо типа `int` лучше использовать тип `long long int`. Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::string s( "4jkk8653kl87-43@Wf23457754345" );
    std::vector<long long int> v;

    for ( std::string::size_type pos = 0; 
          ( pos = s.find_first_of( "0123456789", pos ) ) != std::string::npos; )
    {
        char *p;
        long long int value = std::strtoll( s.c_str() + pos, &p, 10 );
        v.push_back( value );
        pos = p - s.c_str();
    }          

    for ( long long int value : v ) std::cout << value << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Тогда для длинных последовательностей чисел результат будет более точным

```
4 8653 87 43 23457754345
```

Сравните предыдущий вывод последнего числа и данный вывод последнего числа.

Если знак тире - это не разделитель, а знак минуса, то вам достаточно добавить его в символы поиска. Программа будет выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::string s( "4jkk8653kl87-43@Wf23457754345" );
    std::vector<long long int> v;

    for ( std::string::size_type pos = 0; 
          ( pos = s.find_first_of( "-0123456789", pos ) ) != std::string::npos; )
    {
        char *p;
        long long int value = std::strtoll( s.c_str() + pos, &p, 10 );
        if ( !( value == 0 && p[-1] != 0 ) ) v.push_back( value );
        pos = p - s.c_str();
    }          

    for ( long long int value : v ) std::cout << value << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Тогда вывод га консоль будет выглядеть как

```
4 8653 87 -43 23457754345
```

Comment: Что ж вы все `long int` в `int` запихиваете. Вообще говоря некорректно.  Это, пожалуй, наиболее современное решения, хотя, на мой взгляд, задача так и просит решения на pure C.

Comment: @andy.37 По поводу некорректности, вы можете написать письмо в Комитет по Стандартам C и сообщить, что функция  atoi - некорректная. Так что это вопрос не ко мне. Или можете просто почитать книгу по C.

Comment: А ничего, что у тебя вместо `-43` найдено `43`?

Comment: @vlad-from-moscow, да причем тут стандарт. В изначальном примере (где `vector<int>`) вы присваиваете переменной int результат ф-ии strtoll. Оно сработает, но число может получиться другим. Ко второму же примеру кода претензий нет. (да и к первому не претензия, так, скорее ремарка). Кстати, а что, если число в строке и в `long long` не влезет. Забавно, простой, вроде, вопрос, а какая дискуссия))

Comment: @andy.37 Стандарт при том, что, похоже, вы не знаете, как определяется функция atoi. Поэтому я вам и советую почитать книгу по C/

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, ну ткните меня носом, где в Вашем коде используется функция `atoi`.

Comment: @Qwertiy Это хороший вопрос. Но я не думаю, что автору вопроса нужны отрицательные числа. Скорей всего он рассматривает этот знак как разделитель.

Comment: @andy.37 Вот определение функции atoi в стандарте: atoi: (int)strtol(nptr, (char **)NULL, 10) Я лишь привел ее развернутое определение, так как мне нужен был второй параметр функции strtol.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, ОК, убедили. Но как это снимет проблему того, что если число не влезает в инт, то Ваш алгоритм сработает, но сохранит какое-то другое число в векторе? Да, и у автора в вопросе в результатах указано число `-43`.

Comment: @andy.37 Как альтернативу я предложил использовать тип long long int. Просто изначально я не заметил, что у него такие длинные числа. По поводу знака, то надо в поиск символов включить знак минуса.

Answer (score 1):

http://ideone.com/Qu5xmY - вариант без вложенных циклов.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
const char *s="4jkk8653kl87-43@Wf23457754345", *p;
vector <long long> res;
long long cur;
bool in=false, neg;

for(p=s; *p; ++p)
  if(in)
    if(*p>='0' && *p<='9')
      cur = cur*10 + *p - '0';
    else
      res.push_back(neg ? -cur : cur), in=false, p-=*p=='-';
  else
    if((neg=*p=='-'))
      in=true, cur=0;
    else if(*p>='0' && *p<='9')
      in=true, cur=*p-'0';

if(in)
  res.push_back(cur);

for(unsigned q=0; q<res.size(); ++q)
  cout << res[q] << ' ';

return 0;
}
```

На всякий случай: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/473901/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb

Answer (score 1):

Вариант без вложенных циклов с вычислительной сложностью *O(n)*.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const string s("4jkk8653kl87-43@Wf23457754345");
int start = -1;
int count = 0;

inline bool isDigit(const char c)
{
    return '0' <= c && c <= '9';
}

void newNumber()
{
    cout << s.substr(start, count) << endl;
    start = -1;
    count = 0;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
    {
        if (s[i] == '-')
        {
            if (start >= 0) {
                newNumber();
            }

            if (start < 0 && i+1 < s.length() && isDigit(s[i+1]))
            {
                start = i;
                ++i;
                count = 2;
                continue;
            }
        }
        else if (isDigit(s[i]))
        {
            if (start < 0)
                start = i;
            ++count;
            continue;
        }

        if (start >= 0 && count > 0)
             newNumber();
    }
    if (start >= 0 && count > 0)
         newNumber();

    return 0;
}
```

P.S. Строки в число не преобразовывает. Это просто реализация парсинга. Если нужно преобразовать, измените функцию `newNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм может быть таким:
1. Отобрать подстроки из цифр (возможно, со знаком) в массив.
2. Прочитать каждую подстроку как число формата float.
3. Если полученное число не выходит за рамки формата int, записать его в массив результата как int.

На языке PHP программа выглядит так:

```
$maxint = getrandmax();
$str = "4jkk8653kl87-43@Wf23457754345";
print "str = $str";

$cnt = preg_match_all("/[+-]?[0-9]+/", $str, $matches);
$arr = [];
foreach($matches[0] as $strnum){
    sscanf($strnum, "%f", $number);
    if(($number >= -$maxint-1) && ($number <= $maxint)){
        $arr[] = (int)$number;
    } 
}
var_dump($arr);
```

Результат такой:

```
str = 4jkk8653kl87-43@Wf23457754345
array (size=4)
  0 => int 4
  1 => int 8653
  2 => int 87
  3 => int -43
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
        #include <string.h>

        #define pb push_back
        #define mp make_pair
        #define F first
        #define S second
        #define sz(x) (int)x.size()
        #define str(x) (int)strlen(x)
        #define all(x) x.begin(), x.end()
        #define itr ::iterator
        #define rt return
        #define sf scanf
        #define pf printf
        #define bit __builtin_popcountll
        #define forit(it,S) for(__typeof((S).begin()) it = (S).begin(); it != (S).end(); it++)
        #define SABR inline ll IN(){ll x=0,ch=getchar(),f=1;while (!isdigit(ch)&&(ch!='-')&&(ch!=EOF)) ch=getchar();if (ch=='-'){f=-1;ch=getchar();}while (isdigit(ch)){x=(x<<1)+(x<<3)+ch-'0';ch=getchar();}return x*f;}inline void OUT(ll x){if (x<0) putchar('-'),x=-x;if (x>=10) OUT(x/10),putchar(x%10+'0');else putchar(x+'0');}
        #define PI 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510

        using namespace std;

        typedef long long ll;
        typedef unsigned uns;
        typedef pair <int, int> pi;
        typedef vector <int> vi;

        const int MX = (int) 1e6 + 17;
        const int MOD = (int) 1e9 + 7;
        const ll LINF = (ll) 1e18 + 7;
        const int INF = (int) 999999999;


            SABR

            string s;
            vector <int> numbers;
        int main()
        {
            cin >> s;

            for (int i = 0; i < sz(s); i++)
            {
                if (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9')
                {
                    int x = 0;
                    while (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9')
                    {
                        x += s[i] - '0';
                        x *= 10;
                        i++;
                    }
                    numbers.pb(x / 10);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < sz(numbers); i++) cout << numbers[i] << ' ';

            return 0;
        }
```

Как по мне этот самый понятный код. Ничего лишнего и асимптотика О(n);